# How do you end the command when using :c?

Tags: ex-mode

When using the ex command change (c), carriage returns become part of the input, so how do you indicate that you are done entering text?

(I notice that if I hit the backspace, it finishes the command, but I suspect there is a more regular method.)

Comment: At least for `:insert`, a period (.) on its own line was an input terminator. Have you tried that?

Comment: Correct, use a single `.` to exit ex mode